# how to get json data from a angular service using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I am setting data from a angular controller to a service. I need to somehow get this data using jquery or javascript.Is this possible since I am not requesting it from a url?

Angular service

```
    getSeriesData: function () {
        return this.legendSeries;
    },
    setSeriesData: function (legendSeries) {
        this.legendSeries = legendSeries;
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to do that (if you explain the scenario better it might help), but in case you want to share data between an angular application and other JS code (e.g. JSON), one way you could go about is to dispatch a global event from the angular service [for example $(window).trigger('myEvent', myJSON] and then catch this on your separate JS code [window.addEventListener('myEvent'...]

Comment: that is what I was kind of thinking but was not sure what to search for. thanks! that solves my problem!

Comment: cheers. if it works for you feel free to mark the question as answered. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like possible using `injector`

```
var injector = angular.element('body').injector()

$injector.invoke(function (serviceName) {
    var legendSeries = service.legendSeries;
    service.setSeriesData(legendSeries);
});
```